# Change CSS properties of multiple element I add via code

Tags: javascript, html, css, properties

I have an empty ul in HTML and every time I add and remove colors from JavaScript I call ShowColors(). How can I change CSS properties of all those colors? I want to change the height, width, and margin from JavaScript for all colors.

```js
const colorList = document.querySelector(".all-colors");

function ShowColors() {
  if (savedColorsArray.length <= 0)
    return;

  colorList.innerHTML = savedColorsArray.map(color => `
        <li class="color">
            <span class="rect" data-color="${color}" style="background: ${color};"></span>
        </li>`).join("");
}
```

```css
.all-colors .color .rect {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="all-colors"></ul>
```

I tried `document.querySelectorAll('.all-colors .color .rect');` but I get null.

Comment: Include your full code / [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: how are you invoking `ShowColors()`?

Comment: note, that you should not use `innerHTML` as it is slow (reparsing DOM) and poses security issues (XSS injections). The only correct way to create HTML elements is by using `createElement()` function and appending the elements. Alternatively `insertAdjacentHTML` can append too but not entirely correct to sue for such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your selector is right, the span element doesn't accept width and height with the default `display: inline` property. Either you have to use the `display: block` or the `display: inline-block` property. If the answer below is not suitable for you please let me know with your question in detail.

```js
var color_liList = document.querySelectorAll('.all-colors .color .rect');

console.log(color_liList.length);
console.log(color_liList);
```

```css
.all-colors .color .rect {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="all-colors">
  <li class="color">
    <span class="rect" data-color="red" style="background: red;"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="color">
    <span class="rect" data-color="green" style="background: green;"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: spans have a display property: `inline`. You probably meant the right thing but phrased it wrongly.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I solved it by just adding variables `height: var(--rect-height);` in root and then changing them in JavasScript.